# Azure AD Windows 10 openssh login

Tags: ssh, windows-10, entra-id

I have joined a Windows 10 machine to our company Azure AD and can RDP into the VM using my Azure creds.

I have also installed openssh on this machine and would like to be able to remotely connect using my Azure creds but I have not found a way to do this correctly. Any hints as to what username to use here? My Azure username is my email address and not sure @ are allowed in usernames.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows VMs, only RDP is currently supported, you will need the Microsoft RDP client for this to work too: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/howto-vm-sign-in-azure-ad-windows

For Linux VMs, recently SSH Certificate authentication was introduced, don't see any plans to add this to Windows but who knows? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/howto-vm-sign-in-azure-ad-linux

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about a physical machine with the sshd service installed, then that's not supported yet:
https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1787 There's some possible workarounds described here and there, but they're all highly situational and case-specific, and I haven't tried them myself.